# Sitecore Role creation API

Tags: sitecore-api, security

Is there a Sitecore Role creation API similar to item creation ? Can I map user to roles using Sitecore REST API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't exist OOTB this functionality.
You need to build your own Rest API functionality to create Roles.

Please have a look on this PDF : https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/SdnArchive/upload/sitecore6/60/security_api_cookbook_sc60_and_later-a4.pdf and you will find how to manage roles programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for the comment as now i can proceed to build custom APs even though it is a new area too.  Lobaigu, if you have any gihub repos or sample code to start with context initialization it would be great.